# R + rvest + polite for webscraping etsy.com

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am totally new to webscraping and I am probably drowning in a teacup.
I would like to automatically do the following

1. run the following query on etsy.com

https://www.etsy.com/search?q=Christmas+candle&order=most_relevant&view_type=gallery

i.e. simply look for "Christmas candles" on Etsy

2. then retrieve separately the titles and descriptions of the products, possibly giving the number of pages I want to include in my search as an input for my function or pipe.

I had a look at the basic example at

https://github.com/dmi3kno/polite

but when I tried to adapt it to my needs (see the reprex at the end of the post), it failed returning precisely...nothing!

Can anyone point me in the right direction?
Many thanks!

```r
library(polite)
library(rvest)

session <- bow("https://www.cheese.com/by_type", force = TRUE)

result <- scrape(session, query=list(t="semi-soft", per_page=100)) %>%
    html_node("#main-body") %>% 
    html_nodes("h3") %>% 
    html_text()

result
#>   [1] "3-Cheese Italian Blend"            "Abbaye de Citeaux"                
#>   [3] "Abbaye du Mont des Cats"           "Adelost"                          
#>   [5] "ADL Brick Cheese"                  "Ailsa Craig"                      
#>   [7] "Airedale"                          "Aisy Cendre"                      
#>   [9] "Alpe di Frabosa"                   "Alpine Gold"                      
#>  [11] "Alta Badia"                        "Amablu Blue cheese"               
#>  [13] "Ameribella"                        "American Cheese"                  
#>  [15] "Ami du Chambertin"                 "Amsterdammer (British Columbia)"  
#>  [17] "Amul Pizza Mozzarella Cheese"      "Anthotyro Fresco"                 
#>  [19] "Aphrodite Haloumi "                "Appalachian"                      
#>  [21] "Applewood Smoked Chevre"           "Ardrahan"                         
#>  [23] "Armenian String Cheese"            "Aromes au Gene de Marc"           
#>  [25] "Asher Blue"                        "Asiago Pressato DOP"              
#>  [27] "Aura"                              "Azeitao"                          
#>  [29] "Baby Swiss"                        "Baluchon"                         
#>  [31] "Bandal"                            "Basajo"                           
#>  [33] "Basils Original Rauchkäse"         "Baskeriu"                         
#>  [35] "Basket Cheese"                     "Bassigny au porto"                
#>  [37] "Beaumont"                          "Beemster 2% Milk"                 
#>  [39] "Bel Paese"                         "Bergere Bleue"                    
#>  [41] "Bermuda Triangle"                  "Beyaz Peynir"                     
#>  [43] "Bica de Queijo"                    "Bierkase"                         
#>  [45] "Bijou"                             "Blarney Castle"                   
#>  [47] "Bleu Bénédictin"                   "Bleu d'Auvergne"                  
#>  [49] "Bleu Des Causses"                  "Bleu L'Ermite"                    
#>  [51] "Blue Benedictine"                  "Blue Lupine"                      
#>  [53] "Blue Rathgore"                     "Blue Vein (Australian)"           
#>  [55] "Blue Vein Cheese"                  "Blue Yonder"                      
#>  [57] "Bocconcini"                        "Boivin Marbled Cheddar"           
#>  [59] "Bossa"                             "Boulder Chevre"                   
#>  [61] "Brewer's Gold"                     "Brie de Melun"                    
#>  [63] "Brillat-Savarin"                   "Brin"                             
#>  [65] "Brin d'Amour"                      "Bruder Basil"                     
#>  [67] "Brunost"                           "Brutal Blue"                      
#>  [69] "Burwash Rose"                      "Buttercup"                        
#>  [71] "Butterkase"                        "Buttermilk Blue Affinee"          
#>  [73] "Buttermilk Gorgonzola"             "Caciobarricato"                   
#>  [75] "Cacio De Roma®"                    "Caciotta"                         
#>  [77] "Caciotta Al Tartufo"               "Cacow Belle"                      
#>  [79] "Calenzana (Calinzanincu)"          "Cambozola Grand Noir"             
#>  [81] "Cameo"                             "Cana de Cabra"                    
#>  [83] "Cape Vessey"                       "Capra al Fieno"                   
#>  [85] "Capra Nouveau"                     "Cardo "                           
#>  [87] "Carr Valley Glacier Wildfire Blue" "Casatica"                         
#>  [89] "Casciotta di Urbino"               "Cashel Blue"                      
#>  [91] "Castelo Branco"                    "Castle Blue"                      
#>  [93] "Celtic Promise"                    "Chabichou du Poitou"              
#>  [95] "Charolais"                         "Chaumes"                          
#>  [97] "Chevre"                            "Chevre en Marinade"               
#>  [99] "Chile Caciotta"                    "Chile Jack"

## My naive attempt to adapt the code to etsy.com fails miserably

session_etsy <- bow("https://www.etsy.com", force = TRUE)

result_etsy <- scrape(session_etsy, query=list(t="Christmas candle", per_page=100)) %>% html_node("#main-body") %>% 
    html_nodes("h3") %>%
    html_text()


result_etsy
#> character(0)
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: If you look at their ToS you're not allowed to do it. Probably someone can help you, but it should be more correct you point out that it's against site's rule.

Comment: Well, I managed to do it. It seems to me a bit of a gray area. I mean, the site can write what it wants in the ToS, but does it mean it has the right to enforce it? See https://medium.com/@tjwaterman99/web-scraping-is-now-legal-6bf0e5730a78 . I do not think there is anything illegal in what I did.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to extract the product description with the following code for the first page (Note : I used Windows for this example) :

```
library(RDCOMClient)
library(stringr)
IEApp <- COMCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
IEApp[['Visible']] <- TRUE
IEApp$Navigate("https://www.etsy.com/search?q=Christmas+candle&order=most_relevant&view_type=gallery")
Sys.sleep(5)
doc <- IEApp$Document()
Sys.sleep(5)
inner_Text <- doc$documentElement()$innerText()
Sys.sleep(5)

inner_Text_Splitted <- strsplit(inner_Text, "\n")[[1]]
bool_Backslach_R <- inner_Text_Splitted %in% c("\r", " \r", "  \r")
inner_Text_Splitted <- inner_Text_Splitted[!bool_Backslach_R]
inner_Text_Splitted <- inner_Text_Splitted[!(nchar(inner_Text_Splitted) > 2000)]
index_Price_Candle <- which(str_detect(string = inner_Text_Splitted, pattern = "\\d{1,3}\\,\\d{0,2}[:space:]CA\\$"))
inner_Text_Splitted_Price <- inner_Text_Splitted[(min(index_Price_Candle) - 10) : (max(index_Price_Candle) + 10)]
inner_Text_Splitted_Price <- inner_Text_Splitted_Price[-(1 : 7)]

bool_To_Remove <- inner_Text_Splitted_Price %in% c("Chargement...\r", "    Ajouter aux favoris   \r",
                                                   "Publicité d'un créateur Etsy \r", "    Ajouter aux favoris   \r",
                                                   "Populaire  \r", "Top vendeur\r")

inner_Text_Splitted_Price <- inner_Text_Splitted_Price[!bool_To_Remove]
bool_To_Remove <- str_detect(inner_Text_Splitted_Price, pattern = "[:space:]{5}\\(\\d{1,3}\\)[:space:]{1,5}\\r")
inner_Text_Splitted_Price <- inner_Text_Splitted_Price[!bool_To_Remove]

# More cleaning required but the information is there...
# Etsy was in french me for me.
```

Also, if you want to go to another page, you can use

```
# Here, we go to the second page, we added &ref=pagination&page=2 to the original link to go on the second page
IEApp$Navigate("https://www.etsy.com/search?q=Christmas+candle&order=most_relevant&view_type=gallery&ref=pagination&page=2")

# Here, we go to the third page, we added &ref=pagination&page=3 to the original link to go on the third page
IEApp$Navigate("https://www.etsy.com/search?q=Christmas+candle&order=most_relevant&view_type=gallery&ref=pagination&page=3")
```